# Use SQL Select query as wildcard

Tags: sql

Currently, I have the following query:

```
UPDATE table1 SET P='1'
WHERE Recipient IN
(SELECT phone FROM phones WHERE number IN
(SELECT Number FROM users WHERE Username='test'))
```

So, i update a table column with a value where recipient column is found in a list with another criteria. Now, recipient is a phone number and from the incoming data it may be 10 digit or bigger if it has country code in front of it. How, could i change the above query so i can see if recipient is in a list of results but LIKE those results, in order to use wildcards?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? SQL is a query language not the name of a specific DBMS product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `LIKE` clause you can try to match phone numbers with the help of the  `%` operator. So `+1 (813) 890-4530` should match `%(813) 890-4530`. As you haven't posted examples of data in both `recipient` and `phone` tables I will assume the only difference that may exist is the country code. As opposed to `IN` clause I also suggest `INNER JOIN` when possible.

```
UPDATE table1 SET P='1'
FROM phones as p inner join users as u on p.number = u.Number
cross join table1 WHERE  Username='test' and (Recipient LIKE '%' + phone OR phone LIKE '%' + Recipient)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many options:

1) Apply a function to clean up phone numbers so they all look the same. For ex:

UPDATE table1 SET P='1'
WHERE dbo.CleanPhone(Recipient) IN
(SELECT phone FROM phones WHERE number IN
(SELECT Number FROM users WHERE Username='test'))

2) Do an UPDATE using INNER JOIN instead of IN and use LIKE in the JOIN conditions. Something like this:

```
UPDATE t
FROM Table1 t
INNER JOIN Phones p ON Recipient LIKE ...
```